# MUI5 Alert severity backgroundColor change from theme file isn't working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to change the default severity backgroundColor for the Alert component from MUI5 to give every severity my custom background color.
I want to do it with a theme update so the changes will apply to all the components using it but only in this case couldn't find the way to do so.

the component: [Alert MUI](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-alert/)

here is how it looks in dev tools

[image]

I tried to override it with:

```
 MuiAlert: {
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      filled: {
        filledSuccess: {
          backgroundColor: "grey",
        }
      },
    }
  },
},
```

and with:

```
  MuiAlert: {
  styleOverrides: {
    filledSuccess: {
      backgroundColor: "grey",
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: I'm assuming `MuiAlert` object is a property of `overrides` object. right?

Comment: yes and filledSuccess is the rule name